# Can I define IE settings based on the website?

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, settings

I need to define print margin settings based on which of our web pages the users are printing from...

Does anyone know how this can be done??

I've sifted through group policy to no avail.

I also checked to see if I could attach settings to a specific shortcut and couldn't find what i was looking for...

Can anyone provide some assistance?

Thanks in advance.
Grant

Comment: Scripting may be an option? possibly a VBScript?